# Get a view with nodes of users i've flagged?

Tags: drupal, view

another views + flags question.
Situation: users can flag users. Users can also flag nodes. So, I need list of nodes which were flagged by users, flagged by me.

In other words: I need the list of flagged nodes of users I'm following.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these global flags or per user flags?  Do you need the list of nodes flagged by the users your following? OR Do you need the list of nodes flagged by you of the users your following (basically looking for which nodes you both are following)

Comment: I don't have any global flags, only user / node flags.

Comment: >Do you need the list of nodes flagged by the users your following?
exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that in Views, by adding [relationships](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships) to the view. You'd need to add relationships for the flagged users and flagged nodes. Then add filters, based on those relationships.

Comment: I've tried different combinations of relationsships, so far without success